# Auth0 how to login using Lock but then validate the user against my own database?

Tags: jwt, auth0

I am using auth0 to login users in my react app.

When the users hit my callback URL (another react component), is it fine for me to make a request to my own database to validate and update this user?

In my use case, my `users` belong to a `team` and a `team` belongs to a `league`.

There are two types of users - `players` and `owners`.

In order to ensure that my app users are only making requests against `teams` and `leagues` they belong to, I want to add their `teamId` and `leagueId` to the auth0 `user_metadata`, as well as their `userId` local to my app.

Where would I do this in the login flow?  Is this what the callback URL is for?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to set that info (their team/league information) when the user signs-up/logs in? Or will it be set up after, once the user signs up and starts using the app? If it's upon sign-up/login we can look to implement this using an Auth0 Rule (https://auth0.com/docs/rules/current). Otherwise, we can send a patch to [`/api/v2/users/{id}`](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Users/patch_users_by_id) to update `user_metadata`. You can store this information in the `id_token` in a [custom claim](https://auth0.com/docs/scopes/current/custom-claims) depending on your use case.